# How to use the AndroidSDK to calculate routes using imperial units

Tags: here-api

I have set the NavigationManager to use imperial units.  When I use the RouteCalculator the calculated route is shown in metric units

In the map initialization I have set the the navigation manager units

NavigationManager.getInstance().setDistanceUnit(NavigationManager.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL);

Later I build a list of waypoints and after checking that there are at least 2 waypoints call RouteCalculator to create a sample route.

```
    if (waypoints.size() >= 2  && waypoints.get(0) != null && waypoints.get(1) != null) {
        RouteCalculator.getInstance().calculateRoute(waypoints, routeOptions, routeResultList -> {
            // for demo purposes we show only the first route
            RouteCalculator.getInstance().showRoute(map, routeResultList.get(0));
        });
    }
```

When I display the first route details I expect the distances to be listed in miles, however they are listed in kilometres

This is using the Android Premium SDK Version 3.11

Comment: Can you please provide the exact release number you are using and also if this is the starter or premium edition?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport I have same issue with premium SDK v3.11.2.82

Answer (score 0):

The SDK provides such option for guidance only in order to be aligned with Voice package commands. But you can do these transformations on application side if needed.